# Immigration as a step to get financial stability

Tags: immigration

I posted [this](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/83278/can-saving-investing-15-of-your-income-starting-age-25-likely-make-you-a-milli) question and I learned it is extremely difficult to make a good amount of money while living in countries like Pakistan where 1 USD = 107 Rupees. I am 25 and a computer science engineer. In order to make a better living (six figure salaries like people in US, Canada and Australia mention) I am considering the immigration option. Immigration would also bring better health care, education and better jobs overall. Should a person like me consider this option for financial safety and stability?

Comment: It is certainly an idea worth following up on. But don't expect it to be easy.

Comment: Don't necessarily expect a six figure salary either.  Starting salary out of college was $53K when I began my career.

Comment: @Andy: Hope you would have moved up fast.

Comment: It depends on how hard you work and good you are, and making the right career choices.  I think six figures start to much more common after there's at least 10 years of experience behind the person.

Comment: Not enough to post a new answer but a point to note is that while what @Andy said is true, it is also not necessary to make a 6-figure salary to live comfortably (let alone saving and sending some home to family). In some states and small towns you could save a lot. I did that with under $70k in 2-3 years of working. The quality of life is not that bad too. No traffic, pollution, crowd issues, etc.

Answer (score 8):

You can't just emigrate from a country like Pakistan to the USA, Canada or Australia; they will refuse you entry to their country. E.g. for the USA, even if you're are skilled enough that an American company will hire you (which is obviously the first step – so called ['economic refugees'](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/e/economicrefugee.asp) are sent back immediately), you're a long way from obtaining a [green card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_residence_(United_States)). Right now, Pakistan isn't even allowed to participate in the [Green Card Lottery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diversity_Immigrant_Visa).

What you also need to consider is that the [cost of living](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cost_of_living) in those countries is a lot higher. There are websites, like [this one](https://www.expatistan.com/cost-of-living) which allows you to compare them between cities all over the world. So while you would earn a lot more money, you also need to spend a lot more.

Comment: I am a graduate engineer and I can immigrate to any country based on my English results test, qualification and age factor.

Comment: No, you can't (at least not everywhere). Software engineers are in great demand all over the world, but employers and employees need to follow the local laws.

Comment: @FahadUddin From an HR perspective in the US, a company first needs to be willing to sponsor an international employee - which costs the employer thousands of dollars. Also, the employer needs to prove that there are no US citizen that can perform the same duties.

Comment: @MichaelC. and that's (probably) to get a work visa, which is different from *immigration* as intended by the OP. That's how it works for us (I'm working for an IT consultancy firm in The Netherlands).

Comment: @Glorfindel That's true. There are many options to start the immigration process to the US (work-sponsorship, family-sponsorship, etc.) I was assuming with OP's previous question and comment on his educational proficiency, that OP was considering the work route.

Comment: US, Canada, Australia all have skilled worker immigration routes which help people with skilled qualification to apply and immigrate to their country.